# Changing language of facebook Like button doesnt work

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I've added the Facebook Like button to this site in wordpress:

http://www.likemaca.com/

However, the like button is still in english, even though it is the danish language code I added to the header:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/da_DK/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 1):

I viewed your blog source code to check if you added the like using `iframe` or `<div class="fb-like">`, My predictions were right, you added the like-button using `iframe` without adding/sending the parameter `locale=da_DK` to your `iframe` `src`

**Basically you have two solutions**

1. Stick with the `iframe` method and add `locale=da_DK` as below

   ```
   <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FAnchers-Gulvservice-AS%2F309501119143959%3Ffref%3Dts&amp;width&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=65&locale=da_DK" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
   ```

   Notice the last parameter, In this case you won't need the Facebook-JS
2. Replace `iframe` with `<div class="fb-like">`:

   ```
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Anchers-Gulvservice-AS/309501119143959" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
   ```

   Here you will need the Facebook-JS

Comment: Hello Adam Azad, yes and no.

We changed to the iframe method to see if it worked, and even without the Danish language code it shows as it should.

At first we tried the HTML5 version, and thats where I had trouble. I still need this question answered regarding to the HTML5 version, as I'm having a hard time moving the box now.

Casper

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: That, when i'm using the HTML5-version as mentioned in the post, I use the danish language code as facebook tells me to, IE:  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/da_DK/all.js#xfbml=1";

However, it will still be in English. 

I dont know if I'm just a bad coder, but moving the Iframe version in the header(I want it to the right under the search menu) seems to be more trouble than moving the HTML5 version.